# deploying .ashx files in iis server throws object not set to instance error

Tags: windows, iis, server

After deployment of asp.net website, the button click that calls a generic handler file throws the following error.

> Null reference exception: Object not set to instance.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information than this.  The stack trace in the exception should tell you where to look for the null reference.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.